# Total Sum for max sequence per group for point in time

Tags: powerbi, ssas, dax

I am trying to do the following but have been unsuccessful. I have a table with the following structure:

[image]

For each VisitNumber I have several Bill_Ids, each Bill_Id has  several sequences associated with several Visit dates and each Seq Number has an associated Paid amount.

For each [VisitNumber] and for each [Bill_Id], I'd like to be able to grab the max sequence [Seq Number] and sum up all those [Paid] amounts.

Initially, I just set a flag in a calculated column using the following:

```
IsMaxSeq =
VAR BillId = Data[Bill_ID]
VAR SeqNo = Data[Seq Number]
RETURN
    IF (
        COUNTROWS (
            FILTER ( Data, AND ( Data[Seq Number] > SeqNo, Data[Bill_ID] = BillId ) )
        ) > 0,
        "No",
        "Yes"
    )
```

Which is fine for static calculations but I am having a hard time incorporating this dynamically in a measure.

I've been able to get the max sequence for each [Bill_Id] and sum those amounts using the following DAX (and several other versions):

```
MaxSequenceSum =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Data[Paid] ),
    FILTER (
        ALLSELECTED ( Data[Seq Number] ),
        Data[Seq Number] = MAX ( Data[Seq Number] )
    )
)
```

Which yields:

[image]

But as you can see the total is just the max sequence for the entire set. I'd like to obtain the sum of all paid amounts for the max sequence of each [Bill_Id] for each [VisitNumber]. The full set will have thousands of [VisitNumber], each with hundres of [Bill_Ids] and I would like to be able to use this in a card or matrix. I appreciate any help at all, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is that you use a MAX in your measure which will result in the same value when evaluated over your entire dataset as when evaluated for the last period. That's why the outcome of the total is similar to the outcome of the subset with the highest value or [Seq Number] in it.

The trick is to use an iterative calculation so the total dataset always gets evaluated in smaller subsets before being summarized. To do this a [SUMX()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/sumx-function-dax) seems most appropriate. Try the following example:

```
MaxSequenceAlt = 
SUMX (
    SUMMARIZE ( Data , Data[VisitNumber] , Data[Bill_Id] ),
    var _maxSequence = CALCULATE ( MAX ( Data[Seq Number] ) , ALLSELECTED ( Data[Seq Number] ) )
    RETURN
        CALCULATE( 
            SUM ( Data[Amount] ) ,
            Data[Seq Number] = _maxSequence
        )
)
```

When evauluated this results in:

[image]

Comment: Wow what a beautiful solution, thank you so much for your help! I understand what you did I just don't understand how you came up with that lol thanks again!!